# angularjs v1.2.6 - dot notation depth limit in views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that defines an object like this:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.student = {name:"Brandon"};
```

In the view, I'm not able to access the name value using only dot notation:

```
<span>{{data.student['name']}}</span>  <!-- works -->
<span>{{data['student'].name}}</span>  <!-- works -->
<span>{{data.student.name}}</span>     <!-- does not work -->
```

Is this normal behavior, or does this imply there is a bug somewhere?

Comment: they all work, you must be doing something somewhere else that results in this behaviour : http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/9nsTd/2/

Comment: Thank you, the jsfiddle was a great starting point. It helped me narrow the problem down. It turns out it was a bug with ng-csp mode: http://jsfiddle.net/KrNj4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug related to ng-csp mode. It's [been fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5591) since version 1.2.8.